React: why is my conditionally rendered component not being rendered even though condition is being satisfied?
In React, have a parent component which conditionally renders the Output component based on whether there is a selected thread:
<div className="flex-grow overflow-y-auto p-4">
  {myStore.selectedThread ? (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center align-middle h-full">
          <Loader active={true} className="w-36 h-36" />
          <p className="text-xs text-gray-500">Loading messages...</p>
        </div>
      }
    >
      <Output loading={loading} />
    </Suspense>
  ) : (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full">
      <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold text-violet-900 mb-4">
        Hi, {store.profile.fname} {store.profile.lname}!
      </h1>
      <p className="text-gray-500 text-xl mb-8">
        Hit record and let the magic begin.
      </p>
      <RecordingComponent myStore={myStore} />
    </div>
  )}
</div>

and, in the RecordingComponent inside the parent component, I am selecting a thread using a MobX store function after the handlePostTranscription() function:
const audioTranscriberStatus =
  myStore.inputActiveRecord?.audioTranscriber?.status;
console.log(audioTranscriberStatus);
useEffect(() => {
  const handlePostTranscription = async () => {
    const { inputActiveRecord, selectedThread } = myStore;
    if (!inputActiveRecord || selectedThread) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const newThread = await createThread();
      const newThreadId = newThread.thread_id;
      setForceRender((prev) => !prev);

      await updateHistory(inputActiveRecord._id, { threadId: newThreadId });
      const transcriptionText = inputActiveRecord.outputs.join(" ");
      await addMessage(newThreadId, "user", transcriptionText);
      await runAssistant(
        transcriptionText,
        newThreadId,
        "asst_L24bszgfqSOxw3yT0dTOaIzZ",
        "",
      );

      myStore.selectThread(newThreadId);
      console.log(myStore.selectedThread);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in post-transcription handling:", error);
    }
  };

  if (audioTranscriberStatus === "done") {
    handlePostTranscription();
  }
}, [audioTranscriberStatus]);

And in the debug logs, I can see that it is correctly setting the thread, which means, myStore.selectedThread is true which should render the Output component supposedly.
However, my problem is that in the parent component, the Output is not rendering -- I am still seeing the welcome screen. This is not the case when I am using the HistoryPanel component or the TextInputComponent component to set a thread. They both appear to make the Output component render successfully.
From TextInputComponent:
const handleTextSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    setLoading(true);

    // Save the text using the API that goes through the middleware
    const response = await saveText(message);

    if (response.data.history && response.data.history._id) {
      const fetchedHistory = response.data.history;
      let currentThreadId = fetchedHistory.threadId;

      if (!currentThreadId) {
        // Create a new thread if none exists
        const newThread = await createThread();
        currentThreadId = newThread.thread_id;

        // Update history with the new thread ID
        await updateHistory(fetchedHistory._id, {
          threadId: currentThreadId,
        });
      }

      // Add the message to the thread
      await addMessage(currentThreadId, "user", message);

      // Run the assistant on the message
      await runAssistant(
        message,
        currentThreadId,
        "asst_L24bszgfqSOxw3yT0dTOaIzZ",
        "",
      );

      myStore.selectThread(currentThreadId);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    setMessage("");
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

From HistoryPanel:
    const handleHistoryClick = async (threadId) => {
      try {
        setSelectedThreadId(threadId);
        myStore.selectThread(threadId);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error selecting thread:", error);
      }
    };

Finally, myStore:
class myStore {
  tool = {};
  activeSection = "input";
  activeRecord = "";

  threads = [];
  selectedThread = null;
  messages = [];
  loading = false;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }


  // Input Tool properties and methods
  output = "";
  utterances = "";
  outputType = "";
  inputActiveRecord = "";
  inputDocument = null;
  inputForm = {
    title: "",
    inputText: "",
    file: "",
    filename: "",
    audioDuration: 0,
    audioDurationString: "",
    output: "",
  };
  inputUploads = [];
  inputHistories = [];
  clinicalNotesHistories = [];
  questionHistories = [];
  summaryHistories = [];

  get inputOutput() {
    return this.inputForm.output;
  }

  setInputActiveRecord = (val) => {
    this.inputActiveRecord = val;
  };

  setInputDocument = (val) => {
    this.inputDocument = val;
  };

  setActiveHistory = (historyId, section) => {
    this.activeRecord = historyId;
    this.activeSection = section;
  };

  // Thread and message management methods
  fetchThreads = async () => {
    const histories = await fetchThreadHistories();
    this.threads = histories.result.map((history) => ({
      id: history.threadId,
      title: history.title,
    }));
  };

  selectThread = async (threadId) => {
    if (this.selectedThread !== threadId) {
      this.selectedThread = threadId;
      await this.fetchThreadMessages(threadId);
    }
  };

  fetchThreadMessages = async (threadId) => {
    try {
      const fetchedMessages = await fetchMessages(threadId);
      this.setMessages(fetchedMessages); // Use a setter method for setting messages
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch messages:", error);
    }
  };

  setMessages(messages) {
    console.log("Messages being set:", messages);
    this.messages = messages;
  }

  setSelectedThread(threadId) {
    this.selectedThread = threadId;
    console.log("Selected Thread:", myStore.selectedThread);
  }

  async sendMessage(message) {
    if (this.selectedThread) {
      await addMessage(this.selectedThread, "user", message);
      const response = await runAssistant(
        message,
        this.selectedThread,
        "asst_L24bszgfqSOxw3yT0dTOaIzZ",
        ""
      );
      this.messages.push({ role: "user", content: message });
      this.messages.push({ role: "assistant", content: response.content });
    }
  }

  async createNewThread() {
    const threadResponse = await createThread();
    const threadId = threadResponse.thread_id;
    this.threads.push({ id: threadId, title: "New Conversation" });
    await this.selectThread(threadId);
  }
}

Would any of you know what is causing this?
I have also tried just adding a query param to the url that has the threadId and render the Output component if the url has this param, however, in the handlePostTranscription() function, when I use window.location.href or even useHistory, it doesn't even change the url. So there is definitely something with that async function that's messing something up.
EDIT:
It may also be helpful additional information that when handlePostTranscription finishes, and I trigger a hot-reload (eg., when I comment something out and save the editor then go back to the browser localhost), the parent component will re render and show the Output correctly.

Did you try to print the value and see what it is? You have a lot of code, try to be more focused

Yes, I can see that I currently have a selected thread when I try console.log(myStore.selectedThread), which means, that it should be rendering the Output component.

You've changed an object property on myStore, but React only watches the outer object, not its property.
React updates the DOM when you change something it watches; it can then rerun your function or rerender your component and make the changes to the DOM.
We can't see your myStore, but even if it's a useState variable, those are only compared by shallow equality using Object.is. You've changed its state, but React doesn't know to watch for that. Your TextInputComponent and HistoryPanel accidentally trigger this through their setMessage, setLoading, and setSelectedThreadId, which presumably change state variables in a way that React can see; the update to myStore happens by accident in your two working components.
Though there are discouraged ways to force a rerender (see Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?), your best bet may be to call setSelectedThreadId or create a new state variable (e.g. setTranscriptionUpdateTimestamp) to reflect the data change to the component you're trying to update.

I have tried adding within the handlePostTranscription function a setThreadId, and from the parent component, I have tried also to turn threadId into a state and have a useEffect which takes myStore.selectedThread for this threadId, but still, no luck. Debugging logs show that the threadId exists, and is correct, but Output component still isn't being rendered.
I have also edited the original post to include more of myStore.
I'm at my wits' end, really.

It may also be helpful additional information that when handlePostTranscription finishes, and I trigger a hot-reload (eg., when I comment something out and save the editor then go back to the browser localhost), the parent component will re render and show the Output correctly.

Given that MobX is designed to watch and propagate state, have you seen other answers about MobX and async updates? It looks like you might be updating your messages in away that MobX can't see either.
